# Python threads not running synchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, synchronous

I'm writing a program that buys and sells stocks based on certain conditions. It uses Python's threading library to run its methods. Each time a buy is triggered, it checks if the stock is in a boughtStocks dictionary and adds it if it's not there to avoid repeated buying. However, the program occasionally puts in several buy orders (3-4) for a stock instantaneously. I tried locking and joining the threads so they run synchronously but neither have fixed the issue.

The simplified code of the program looks like this:

```
import threading
from obj import MyObj

obj = MyObj()
ilock = threading.Lock()

# Triggers sell orders and removes stocks from boughtStocks dictionary.
def updateStocks():
    with ilock:
        obj.sellCheck()
        obj.updateOrders()

# Triggers buy orders if stock is not in boughtStocks and adds to boughtStocks
def scanStocks():
    with ilock:
        for index in range(0,30):
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=obj.runScan, args=[index])
            t1.start()

def main():
    while obj.marketOpen():
        updateThread = threading.Thread(target=updateStocks)
        scanThread = threading.Thread(target=scanStocks)
        threads = [updateThread, scanThread]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
            t.join()
```

Each time scanStocks() runs, it goes through a list of stocks and puts in a buy order if conditions are met before adding it to the boughtStocks dictionary. It uses a check like

```
if stock not in self.boughtStocks:
    check conditions here
```

I know I'm not showing the detailed workings of the program, but I'm hoping this is a common threading issue that can be identified based on the code I provided. Once a stock is bought and added to the boughtStocks dictionary, it should not be bought again until it is removed from that dictionary. This issue of multiple orders happens maybe 10% of the time. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Re, "I tried locking and joining the threads so they run synchronously but..." That's just the two threads started by your `main()` function. What about the thirty threads that are started by your `scanStocks()` function?

Comment: My intention is for those 30 threads to run, then wait for the update threads to run, and repeat that. When I use print statements, it works as intended by showing 30 stock scans, and then updating, and then 30 scans, etc. Considering the multiple buy problem occurs only occasionally and all the orders are placed instantaneously, I think the problem is something else.

Comment: Well, like you said, all of the code in your example is effectively single-threaded. So, either this question has nothing to do with multithreading, or else it's a question about what happens when you concurrently execute thirty calls to `runScan(i)`. But since the definition of `runScan()` does not appear in your question, nobody's going to be able to tell you why it does whatever it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect the `Lock` object to work in a way that it does not.
Let's go through the code step by step. I understand that `main` is the entry point.

1. Creates two threads, one that will run `updateStocks` and other that will run
   `scanStocks`
2. Starts the first thread and waits for it to finish. This is equivalent to
   just call `updateStocks()`: there no use for threads here.
   Let's see what this call does:

   1. 'updateStocks' acquires a `Lock` and calls `obj.sellCheck()` and
      `obj.updateOrders()`. There seems to be no use for the `Lock` here
      since nothing is running concurrently, but see below.
3. Starts the second thread and waits for it to finish. This is equivalent to
   just call `scanStocks()`. Again, there no use for threads here. Let's see
   what `scanStocks()` does:

   1. `scanStocks()` acquires the lock and starts 30 threads running
      `obj.runScan`, passing values from `0` to `29` as parameters. These threads run at the same time and are never joined.
   2. `scanStocks()` releases the `Lock` and exits. The threads that were
      started may or may not have finished.
4. If the markets are open, go back to step one. Maybe some thread running `obj.runScan` is still running, and maybe it still is the next time more `scanStocks` threads are started again.

So, in resume, the the lock does not protect any resource here. It is possible to have many generations of `scanStocks` running concurrently.

Without knowing more about the logic of the program, like where are the `dicts` accessed, it is not possible to provide further help.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write the explanation. I seemed to have fixed the problem by creating a time.sleep() pause between the scanThread and updateThread.